# Angular 9 throwing errors when ngx-bootstrap is used

Tags: angular, frontend, angular8, visual-web-developer, angular9

I just upgraded my project to Angular 9 on 07FEB20 and ever since whenever I add a library (is that the right word?) (such as ngx-bootstrap or ngx-gallery, which i'm using in another project and they're fine) I get this error in my console upon ng serve: 
[image]

I goes away when I uninstall said libraries, but that's obviously not helpful because I'm at a stalemate as to what I can do with my project now.

Here are my imports: 
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to downgrade Angular to some version of 8? I've tried the `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.1.4` (my previous version) but it seems like that's not enough to actually revert the project as not all elements are reverted to the 8 version.

I've been trying and Googling for 3 days and I'm at a loss as to how to integrate these libraries without errors coming up.

Oh also, I'm getting errors when these libraries are installed about Renderer vs  Renderer2.  Even changing those so they parse doesn't help. I still get the "cannot read property 'id'" error.

***EDIT***:
main.ts:
[image]

Comment: can you put your code in stackblitz, I can have a look, it should be something else or something is missing

Comment: You're not supposed to import `BsModalService` and `BsModalRef` in your NgModule

Comment: Can you share your `main.ts`?

Comment: edited to show main.ts

Comment: Thanks. I've searched for the issue online, and it seems to usually be an issue with importing both `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule`. Are you sure it has anything to do with your other libraries?

Comment: Also, in the future, please just copy and paste your code (and use the code formatting button in stackoverflow's editor) instead of sharing screen dumps.

Comment: Do you need to have both ngx-bootstrap and ng-bootstrap installed?

Answer (score 1):

to downgrade you can try

```
ng --version
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@8._._
ng --version
```

NOTE: put in the angular 8 version to where cli@8.*.*

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that angular 8 (whatever version you were previously using) is listed in your dependencies in package.json.

Instead of starting server with `ng serve` start (from inside of angular project directory) using `node_modules/.bin/ng serve`

Using this method, You can have current version installed globally, yet still run certain projects using legacy versions (without the uninstall/reinstall headaches.)

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json you can downgrade your angular cli version by changing `@angular/cli: 9.x.x` to `@angular/cli: 8.x.x`